# GL_TEXTURE_3D color and stencil FBO attachments

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I am doing a [layered rendering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images) to an offscreen FBO using OpenGL 4.3.I used [GL_TEXTURE_3D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage3D.xml) with several layers as COLOR attachment.Then I use geometry shader to index into different layers when writing the output.It works ok.Now I need also stencil attachment for stencil test I am performing during the rendering.First I tried just to attach a render buffer as in the case with 2D attachments.

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,
GL_RENDERBUFFER, _stencilBuffer)
```

In this case,when checking FBO for completeness I am getting frame buffer error:

> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS_ARB

Then I assumed that if the color attachment is 3D so the stencil attachment also must be 3D.And because there is no 3D render buffer I tried to attach a 3D texture for depth stencil slot of the FBO.

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, depth,
0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8);
```

Where **width** - texture width,**height**-texture height,**depth**-number of layers inside texture 3D.

```
//Attach to FBO:
 
 glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, texId, 0));
```

Doing it this way I am getting:

> `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE`
>
> INVALID_OPERATION

I have searched any possible example to find how such a setup should be done,but found nothing.`I also tried to use GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY  instead,but same problem.` (for some reason this actually fixed the problem which persisted in my earlier tests)

**UPDATE**

My fault as got confused with some of my findings during the debug.Basically half of what I wrote above can be discarded.But because other people may get into the same issues I will explain what happened.

At first,when I attached a 3d texture to COLOR attachment of FBO I created a render buffer for GL_DEPTH_STENCIL attachment.And yes,on completeness check I got:

> ```
> GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS_ARB
> ```

Next,I tried instead:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height, depth,
0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8);
```

which thrown:

> INVALID_OPERATION

Now,instead of **GL_TEXTURE_3D** target I tried **GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY** which finally caused the FBO to be complete.So,while I would still like to understand why **GL_TEXTURE_3D** causes INVALID_OPERATION(feel free to post an answer),this change  has solved the problem.

Comment: Can you post the actual numeric code you get from glCheckFramebufferStatus?

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh Man!You are back!We were missing you  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the spec, `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS` means (quoted from OpenGL 4.5 spec):

> If any framebuffer attachment is layered, all populated attachments must be layered. Additionally, all populated color attachments must be from textures of the same target (three-dimensional, one- or two-dimensional array, cube map, or cube map array textures).

Based on the first part of this, your initial attempt of using a single layer stencil attachment with a layered 3D texture color attachment was clearly illegal.

The second part sounds somewhat unclear to me. Since it only talks about "color attachments", it suggests that using a `GL_TEXTURE_3D` color attachment and a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` stencil attachment would be legal. But I'm not convinced that this is actually the intention. Unfortunately I couldn't find additional confirmation of this in the rest of the spec.

Using `GL_TEXTURE_3D` for a stencil or depth/stencil texture is a non-starter. There's no such thing as a 3D stencil texture. From the 4.5 spec, pages 191-192 in section "8.5 Texture Image Specification"

> Textures with a base internal format of DEPTH_COMPONENT, DEPTH_STENCIL, or STENCIL_INDEX are supported by texture image speciﬁcation commands only if target is TEXTURE_1D, TEXTURE_2D, TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE_ARRAY, TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, PROXY_TEXTURE_1D, PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, PROXY_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, PROXY_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, PROXY_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, PROXY_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE_ARRAY, PROXY_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, PROXY_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, or PROXY_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY.

That's a long list, but `TEXTURE_3D` is not in it.

Based on this, I believe that what you found to be working is the only option. You need to use textures with target `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` for both the color and stencil attachment.